# Split Java string on spaces with special characters and complications

Tags: java, regex, string, parsing, special-characters

I have an input string like :

```
-a  var1=Bat"m/an  -b   var2=" -a="lol "  -c  var3=" M^a%g-i=c "
```

After splitting I should get :

***Output***

```
- -a
- var1=Bat"m/an
- -b
- var2=" -a="lol "
- -c
- var3=" M^a%g-i=c "
```

Rules:

- format is something like `-(char)(atleast one space)variable=value`
- value can have any special characters except spaces ex. `Bat"m/an`
- value can have spaces if in quotes ex. `" -a="lol "` or `" M^a%g-i=c "`

I have written the regex but quotes inside quotes is messing it up :

```
(?:"[^"]*"|\S)+
```

Also I tried to parse character wise or split on `="` but I'm facing ambiguity as they can be inside quotes too.

Comment: So, are these key-value like pairs?

Comment: You are saying that values can have spaces if in quotes - it sounds like in this case `var1=Bat"m/an  -b   var2="` shouldn't be split at all, yet you say that it should be split into `var1=Bat"m/an`, `-b` and `var2=" -a="lol "`. Can you please be clear about your expected output?

Comment: If the `var` part is always the same and only digits vary, you may use [`\B(-[a-z])\s+(var\d+=.*?)\s*(?=\B-[a-z]\s+var\d+=|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/iPKHeO/1)

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Quotes around value start only after 'variable=' like variable="value" but in var1=Bat"m/an  -b   var2=" -a="lol " ... var1=Bat"m/an ... value is Bat"m/an and not Bat"m/an  -b   var2=" as the quote doesn't start immediately after '='

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew variable is like the common variable names allowed in java.

Comment: And what about `var2=" -a="lol "`? You need to handle un-escaped quotes within the value?

Comment: @Sneh Please try (-[a-z]|[^\s][^\s]*="?[^"]*"?[^\s]*) as shared in my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex for **matching** with a lookahead assertion:

```
-?[a-z_]\w*(?:=".*?"(?=\h+(?:-[a-z](?=\h|$)|[a-z]\w*=)|$)|\S+)?
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/d5KbXd/4)

**RegEx Explanation:**

- `-?`: Start with an optional hyphen
- `[a-z_]\w*`: match a variable that starts with a lowercase letter or underscore followed by 0+ word characters
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `".*?"(?=...<expression>)`: Match quoted string that starts and ends with double quote. Using lookahead we assert that we have another variable or end of line ahead.
  - `|`: OR
  - `\S+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `)`: End non-capture group

Comment: The requirements are too unclear. The above solution will fail with [`-a  var1=Bat"m/an  -b   var2=-a="lol-c" s-c -c var3=" M^a%g-i=c "`](https://regex101.com/r/iPKHeO/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew what I am getting from OP requirement is that it is kind of accepting arguement parameters which should either start with - symbol and then a key value pair.

Comment: Wiktor: I am not sure about `s-c` as that is not a valid Java variable name

Comment: @anubhava I do believe your answer is correct as OP wanted, but dont you think that different parameters should be captured as a group instead of non capturing group

Comment: @anubhava This won't work if inner quotes have spaces too like var=" " hi " "

Comment: @Sneh: Try this regex: `-?[a-z_]\w*(?:=".*?"(?=\h+(?:-[a-z](?=\h|$)|[a-z]\w*=)|$)|\S+)?` or https://regex101.com/r/d5KbXd/4

Answer (score 0):

You can try something as below:

```
(-[a-z]|[^\s][^\s]*="?[^"]*"?[^\s]*)
```

where all the parameters and their values will be captured as a separate group

Explanation:

```
Capturing Group (-[a-z]|[^\s][^\s]*="?[^"]*"?[^\s]*)
1st Alternative -[a-z]
2nd Alternative [^\s][^\s]*="?[^"]*"?[^\s]*
[^\s] - A character which should not be a space
[^\s]* - Matches all non space characters
= checks for equal to as mandatory
= matches the character = literally (case sensitive)
"? checks if " symbol is there
[^"]* checks for all symbols that are not as "
"? Again check for " as option
[^\s]* Finally again check for all non space characters
```

[Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/WcsYZx/1)

Hope that helps :) .